# Splunk: schedule an alert with two different frequencies (without overlapping)

Tags: cron, splunk

I have one Splunk alert which should run infrequent at night and more frequent at day.

```
00:00 - 06:00 every 30 minutes
*/30 0-6 * * *
At every 30th minute past every hour from 0 through 6.
```

```
08:00 - 22:00 every 10 minutes
*/10 8-22 * * *
At every 10th minute past every hour from 8 through 22.
```

Can I mix them using one cron expression?

Or do I have to clone the alert and as a trade-off everything is redudant (except the cron expression) then?

Answer (score 2):

Each alert/scheduled search is allowed a single cron schedule.  If you need multiple schedules then the alert must be cloned.